# Getting Stackblitz to run in separate tab?

Tags: angular, stackblitz

So up until now Angular Stackblitz projects have been running just fine in a separate Tab, however after recent upgrades this no longer works in both Firefox and Chrome.

[I found this issue](https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/162) and [this documentation](https://developer.stackblitz.com/platform/webcontainers/browser-config) and I've added the exceptions to both Chrome and Firefox, but when I try to open the project in a separate Tab, no bieno.  For Chrome it spins for a little bit, and then shows this:

```
{"originalErr":{}}
```

Any ideas?

This is running on the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox on MacOS:

```
ProductName:        macOS
ProductVersion:     13.5.2
BuildVersion:       22G91
```

Comment: Same here did you get this figured out

Comment: Not yet.  Hopefully some insight is brought to this soon, because Stackblitz is such an awesome tool!!

Comment: Same problem for me. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Did you end up having a call with them? any outcome?

Comment: We scheduled a call, but they canceled 5 minutes before the it was supposed to take place.  I'm sure once they have some concrete solutions they will post them.  Maybe give them a ping on the issue and let them know that a lot of us would really love to have a work around for this.  I've started using CodeSandbox and it opens the workspace in a new tab without a hitch and is quite fast, so perhaps that would be something  for the Stackblitz team to study.

Comment: It is the same for me....